# Помощь по установке OpenCart

Tags: opencart, php, html

Добрый день!
Подскажите пожалуйста, кто разбирается, с чем может быть связанна проблема:
Залил все из папки upload в корневую, www, захожу на сайт и мне пишет - 
**Forbidden**
You don't have permission to access / on this server.

Comment: Права, вроде как выставил. где надо. И конфиг файлы переименовал в нужные.

Answer (score 1):

Все. Разобрался.
Оказывается FileZilla не все файлы загрузила.
Как минимум не оказалось index.php в корне.